# Twitter API @Anywhere: Include hash tag in tweet box?

Tags: twitter, tweets, hashtag, twitter-anywhere

I am using the Twitter API @Anywhere Tweet Box for a project I am working on. It is supposed to simply let people tweet a statement with a hash-tagged word included in the tweet. Now, I know there is the defaultContent function, but the problem is that the text is supposed to go in front of the hashtag, not after. If people start writing in the text box, the hashtag would be in front of the text (unless they specifically write it in front of the hashtag). Is there any way to "pre-include" a hashtag term, but not make it show up in the text box?

Any help is much appreciated!